# How to get string in between N ' | ' and (n+1) ' | ' Occurence in python

Tags: python

My string is as follow

```
2              | 848       | Seconds        |  660.00   |  900.00   | OK
```

I would like to get the data before the first ' | ' 
and then between the first ' | '  and the second ' | ' 
until the last one. I also would like to remove spaces and/or tabs.

\|(^\|)*\|

I tried this to get rid of ' | ' in between ' | ' but it doesn't work.
Any Idea?

Thank you

Comment: You "need" to use regex? Sounds like homework.

Comment: @internet_user: which is not a problem on Stack Overflow, so why do you feel the need to mention it?

Comment: When you say "text", do you mean a string? Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and be specific. Also make clear, if it is a homework/assignment and specify, what you have tried to " get rid of | in between |".

Comment: So what is the result you *need* for this example?

Comment: @internet_user I "need" to use regex because I want both to know how to do it using regex and because my whole parser is using regex and I want to keep it that way, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regexps for this:

```
>>> s = "2              | 848       | Seconds        |  660.00   |  900.00   | OK"
>>> parts = [part.strip() for part in s.split("|")]
>>> parts
['2', '848', 'Seconds', '660.00', '900.00', 'OK']
>>> parts[0]
'2'
>>> parts[2]
'Seconds'
>>> parts[-1]
'OK'
>>> "|".join(parts)
'2|848|Seconds|660.00|900.00|OK'
```

Comment: This is the better solution, but OP wants to use `regex`

Comment: I like this solution and if I don't find an easy way to do it using regex I will use your solution, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: `[^\s\|\t]+`

**Details**:

`[^\s|]` Match a single character not present in the list

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

`\s` matches any whitespace character

`\|` matches the character |

`\t` matches a tab character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TH0hiM/3)

Comment: What if `2 | some value`?

Comment: @ctwheels I don't think he has that case.

Comment: This doesn't get the (N+1)th field as requested. That would be more like `^(?:[^|]*\|){N}([^|]*)`. That said, using `split` (as shown in another answer) is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [`split` can use a regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split) for its split-on argument. For this simple case it has no obvious advantages over a plain `split`, other than you don't need a separate `strip` to remove the whitespace around the `|`.

```
import re

str = "2              | 848       | Seconds        |  660.00   |  900.00   | OK"
result = re.split(r'\s*\|\s*', str)
```

Result:

```
['2', '848', 'Seconds', '660.00', '900.00', 'OK']
```

Answer (score 0):

bruno's approach is very good for removing these extra lines of code

```
givenText = "2              | 848       | Seconds        |  660.00   |  900.00   | OK"

desiredText = []
givenTextList = givenText.split("|")
for i in givenTextList:
    desiredText.insert(len(desiredText), i.strip())
print(desiredText)
```

Here split is used to return a list from given string according to  the given parameter
And strip is used to remove all those extra spaces at the end